# R lattice levelplot - combine many plots together with one color key on same scale

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to plot a 3x3 grid of levelplots which are all on the same color scale with one combined color key.

I have found `latticeExtra` and its ability to override `c` and combine `trellis` objects together, with the `merge.legends` flag. However, when I do this I get multiple color keys.

is a picture of what it looks like with only three of the plots.
[image: Here] 
And here is the code where I do this:

```
t1 <- levelplot(counts[[1]], main="", col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("white","red"))(256))
t2 <- levelplot(counts[[2]], main="", col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("white","red"))(256))
t3 <-  levelplot(counts[[3]], main="", col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("white","red"))(256))

plots <- c(t1, t2, t3, merge.legends=T)
print(plots)
```

I also would ideally like to not have to manually make each `trellis` object its own variable, but rather a member of a list:

```
plots <- list()
for (i in 1:length(counts)){
  if (i %% 3 == 0) {
    plots[[i]] <- levelplot(counts[[i]], main="", col.regions=colorRampPalette(c("white","red"))(256))
  }
}
plots <- c(unlist(plots), merge.legends=T)
```

But when I try to do this it seems that the `c` function is not overridden correctly. I have tried not using `unlist`, as well as making `plots` a vector, and they do not work.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 3):

Note that `merge.legends = TRUE` results in separate legends per plot. If you want to merge single legends using `c.trellis`, you have to set `merge.legends = FALSE` (somewhat counter-intuitive, I know...). Based on a levelplot example from `?c.trellis`:

```
# Levelplot
levObj <- levelplot(prop.table(WorldPhones, 1) * 100)

# Combination via `c.trellis`
comb_levObj <- c(levObj, levObj, layout = c(1, 2), merge.legends = FALSE)
print(comb_levObj)
```

[image: c.trellis]

Comment: Any idea how to get the labels to show up on the same side of the chart?

Comment: `update(comb_levObj, scales = list(alternating = 1))`. See also `?xyplot`.